# WHILE conditions are not working properly in MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, while-loop, xampp

I am learning MySQL through self-practice. In a project, I want to create a transfer module using MySQL (phpMyAdmin). Unfortunately, the WHERE conditions are not working well. I execute the query using the XAMPP application. A part of the query is -

```
 SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `emp_id`,
            `emp_name`,
            `present_posting`,
            `curr_zone`,
            `office_ID1` AS `new_office`,
            `Zone1` AS `new_zone`,
            `office_ID1` AS `C1`,
            `post`,
            `preference`,
            `curr_zone_id`
    FROM
        `transfer_applications`
    WHERE
        `Mutual Accepted` != 'Mutual Accepted'
    ORDER BY `apID` ASC) `aa`
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        `zone_ID`, `ZONE`, `office_ID`, `office_Vacancy`
    FROM
        `vacancy`) `ab` ON `aa`.`C1` = `ab`.`office_ID`
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        `zid`, `max_min_vacancy`
    FROM
        `capping_vacancy`) `ac` ON `aa`.`new_zone` = `ac`.`zid`
WHERE
    ((`curr_zone_id` != `new_zone`
        AND (`max_min_vacancy` < 150
        AND `max_min_vacancy` > 1)
        AND `station_Vacancy` > 0
        AND `post` = 4
        AND `apID` = x + 1)
        OR (`curr_zone_id` = `new_zone`
        AND `station_Vacancy` > 0))
```

The problem is that it allows transfer even if there is no vacancy available that is the minimum capping in WHERE ( `max_min_vacancy` > 1 ) is not working. I am unable to find out the reason why it skips this condition while all other conditions in the WHERE are working fine. Kindly help me to find out the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: with out tables and data we also can't find out, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: while is only allowed in procedures as are other loop or cursor, maybe that will help you

Comment: Also, you don’t need all those sub-selects - just join the tables together. The ORDER BY is also going to have no effect

Comment: @nbk yes, it is a part of a procedure and using WHILE. Unfortunately, it does not consider the (max_min_vacancy > 1)

Comment: @nbk my original query is very long. So I post a part which has an issue.

Comment: It is an art to redact an still have a complete query so that we can understand you. In g enaral remove all but 1 table and no where ca
Läuse and see if you get it to run, after that add one join after another till you have all columns for the select and then add one where condition after another and check on every step if you still get all rows

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause is connected by an `OR`, so if the first Boolean expression is FALSE (ie. max_min_vacancy <=1), it is still TRUE as long as the second boolean expression returns TRUE.

```
...
WHERE
    (
     (
      `curr_zone_id` != `new_zone`    AND 
         (
          `max_min_vacancy` < 150     AND 
          `max_min_vacancy` > 1             -- if max_min_vacancy <= 1 --> FALSE
         )                            AND 
       `station_Vacancy` > 0          AND 
       `post` = 4                     AND 
       `apID` = x + 1
     )
  OR (                                      -- But this condition is TRUE
      `curr_zone_id` = `new_zone`     AND 
      `station_Vacancy` > 0
     )
    )
```

Comment: Yes, because I want capping for inter zonal transfer only but thanks as I got attention where I was wrong because of your answer. Thanks again.